# Django REST: Custom field, list may not be empty

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add the employees field to my custom user model in Django REST 2.2. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNljn.png) is how I implemented my custom user (first answer). The employees field is just a list of custom users (so it's related to itself, with a many-to-many relationship).

When I try to add a custom user model from the django interface, it says "this list may not be empty". How can I make it so it can be empty? I thought that's what I added "required=False" for.

[image]

**users/models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    employees = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name='employees')
```

**users/serializers.py** (CustomRegisterSerializer is used for registering with rest-auth, CustomUserSerializer is used to view and edit)

```
class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
        employees = serializers.RelatedField(many=True, required=False, queryset=CustomUser.objects.all())

        def get_cleaned_data(self):
            data_dict = super().get_cleaned_data()
            data_dict['employees'] = self.validated_data.get('employees', '')
            return data_dict

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'employees')
```

**users/views.py**

```
class CustomUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer
```